# Which solution is the right one??

Tags: calculus, power-series, roots

If we want to solve the equation $sec^2(x)$ for finding the all roots(real and complex), we have two ways:
1-Direct solving for $sec^2(x)=0$
2-Or by convert the above equation to polynomial series  as follow
$a_{0}+a_{1}x+a_{2}x^2+a_{3}x^3......a_{n}x^n=0$

In the first way, there are no roots in real and complex plane, but in the second way there are infinity roots 
Which solution is the right one?

Answer (score 1):

The Fundamental Theorem of Algebra can not be extended to power series.

Example:

$$e^z\neq 0$$
that is
$$1+z+\frac{z^2}{2!}+\frac {z^3}{3!}+\cdots\neq 0$$

Comment: In the complex plane, there are infinity roots for $e^x=0$

Comment: What?? You have just spoiled the whole complex analysis... :)

Comment: If you truncate the series at any point, the roots are $\approx-N$ where $N$ gets larger and larger as you add more terms. Eventually all of the roots go to $-\infty$.